# Can gamification lead to better group cooperation?

Tags: gamification, sociology

I was wondering. **Would it be possible to stimulate an individuals sense of group by gamification?**

For those who don’t know, gamification is a method of making a game out of the mundane.

For example:
If you earn a badge for every time you correct something on StackExchange. Would that be a good enough ‘reward’ for most people to keep doing it and not giving up after some time?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE Otsukisama.  What have you found out so far yourself with regard to the effects of *gamification* on individuals?  What may be causing problems or confusion?  Providing references to what you know helps to formulate an answer which will not be repeating what you already know, whilst concentrating on what may be causing problems or confusion.

Comment: Related: **[How do cooperative vs. competitive activities impact the learning patterns of an individual?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/1398/how-do-cooperative-vs-competitive-activities-impact-the-learning-patterns-of-an)**